# User for the procmail log file

Tags: linux, exim, procmail

I configured exim to deliver local mail via procmail to maildirs in a pretty standard way: (`exim4.conf`)

```
procmail_pipe:
   driver = pipe
   command = /usr/bin/procmail -d $local_part
   return_path_add
   delivery_date_add
   envelope_to_add
   check_string = "From "
   escape_string = ">From "
   user = $local_part
   group = mail
```

and in `/etc/procmailrc`

```
MAILDIR=$HOME/
LOGFILE=procmail.log
LOCKFILE=procmail.lock
DEFAULT=.maildir/
```

The owner of the .maildir itself is correct -- `$user:mail`, but for some reason the log file is `root:mail`.

How can I change it to `$user:mail` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procmail invokes /etc/procmailrc with root privileges, if it can.

Since you're using Exim to set the user, you don't need procmail to do it for you.  You might be able to just remove the setuid bit from the procmail binary to fix this -- depends if you need anything else to be invoking procmail.